# Unable to access jarfile /home/user/jelastic-cli.jar

Tags: cygwin, jelastic

I'm trying the **Jelastic CLI** on my local machine. I'm following [this example](https://docs.jelastic.com/cli#install).

When I'm executing:

`curl -s ftp://ftp.jelastic.com/pub/cli/jelastic-cli-installer.sh | bash`

I get this:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 9185k  100 9185k    0     0  2721k      0  0:00:03  0:00:03 --:--:-- 2725k
Error: Unable to access jarfile /home/tvulpe/jelastic-cli.jar
```

I'm using the `Cygwin` environment.

Comment: Hi @tvulpe, just made some changes to your post in order to improve its clarity, feel free to edit it again if you feel I changed something relevant to your intentions. Report: Formatted code, text and link and added the Cygwin tag (since its the environment the OP is working on).

Comment: Hello,
What do you mean when you tell "I'm using Cygwin environment"?

Answer (score 0):

Java for Windows is unable to access the file from Unix-like environment like Cygwin. It wouldn't work properly even if we fix the step with access.
To run CLI in Cygwin you have to use Java for Linux in Cygwin or just use VirtualBox with Linux.